# Django: FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY vs DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY

Tags: django

I am working with Django 2.2 and got stuck with file upload size validation. I have read django documentation:

[DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE)
[FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE)

I only set DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY (to 20 MB), as mentioned in documentation:

> The check is done when accessing request.body or request.POST and is
>   calculated against the total request size excluding any file upload
>   data.

But in my project it also checks my uploading file size in request.FILES.

Can someone explain differences between FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY and DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY? And how to use them properly?

Comment: Can you explain “it also checks my uploading file size”?

Comment: @dirkgroten as I understand DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY should exclude uploaded files size, which are in request.FILES, but when it is set and FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY is default, I can upload files up to size which is set in DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY.

Comment: On your development environment? And how do you upload the files exactly?

Answer (score 3):

**DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY**

The check is done when accessing request.body or request.POST and is calculated against the total request size **excluding any file upload data.**

**FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE**

The maximum size (in bytes) that an upload will be **before it gets streamed to** the file system. If uploading files are larger than FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE, the data of files will be streamed to **FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR**
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#file-upload-temp-dir

I don't think you have to set FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE, because it's the size of memory cache.

Comment: Thank you for an answer, maybe you could clarify with an example how total request size is calculated when DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY is set to 20mb and FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE is default and when FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE is set as an example to 20mb? How do FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE and DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE correlate?

Comment: DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY is set as 20M, FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE is set as 15M. If you upload a file(25M), an error will occur as in your question.  So, DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY is changed to 30M, there will be no error. <br>if the uploaded data size of the file is little than 15M, the data is in memory. If the uploaded size is more than 15M, the data will be streamed to disk.

Answer (score 2):

`FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY` will load the file contents into the RAM, if the request body or the file which is uploaded is more than `FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY` then the file will be stored in the `/tmp` directory.

You can restrict the file size in the webserver (Nginx) by adding `client_max_body_size 20M;`

Here 20 megabytes is the maximum data that request body can have. So if you are uploading a file more than 20 MB, the webserver will not accept it.

Comment: Thank you for an answer, maybe you could clarify with examples how FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY and DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY correlate? When one is set to something or both is set to something.

Comment: They are unrelated.