# Docker Container exited with code 247 when getting data from GCP

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I'm running a Flask API inside a Docker Container.

My application has to download files from Google Cloud, and sometimes, after some minutes of execution, my container exits with the following message:
`pm-api exited with code 247`

I am not sure, but I think it might be related to the size of the data I'm trying to download from GCP, becuse I'm using a query and I don't seem to have any problem whem limiting the number of rows I get from it.

Could be data-size related? And if so, how can I configure my docker container to not break when downloading/saving large files?

Answer (score 4):

In order to solve this problem I had to increase the size of my docker container. This is found in settings resources. Increasing the memory removed this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, possibly due to the large file size.

You may have to define `FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE` larger than your downloading file.[What is code 247](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323159/what-is-code-247-returned-by-django-1-2-4-development-server)

Also refer
[max-memory-vs-data-upload-max-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60429218/django-file-upload-max-memory-vs-data-upload-max-memory)

Comment: All those links refer to projects using Django. I'm **not** using Django.

Comment: Is independant the exit code that you have with the language that you use. django and flask use python. the difference is framwork but the issue is related.

Comment: Well, it might be, but I can't define a value for FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE because it is from Django.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue. docker container (python code processing some data) exited

> command terminated with exit code 247

my docker container is running on k8s.

the issue was caused because I set the k8s resources memory limit to 4GB, but the python container needs to use >4GB memory. after I increase the memory limit to 8GB, the issue is sovled.

but about why the exit code is 247, I don't find the answer. from the [docker exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297616/what-is-the-authoritative-list-of-docker-run-exit-codes), it doesn't have code 247.